# map reduce count based on columns

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am currently learning mapreduce programming and was able to do single key single value, multiple key single value using writable interface.
I am confused as to how to select appropriate the key and value for the following scenario or dataset

> **Subject    MaleName     FemaleName**
>
> chemistry    Mike         Hillary
>
> physics    Gerald       Hillary
>
> social     Mike         Amber

Output expected is

> Chemistry Mike Hillary 2 2
>
> physics Gerald Hillary 1 2
>
> social  Mike Amber 2 1

4th column will give count of Male Name in the entire data set and 5th should display count of female name in the data set.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: impossible to do that with a single map-reduce phase. you'll have to implement additional phase(s) for joining original dataset with counts

Comment: will this be reduce phase join?

Comment: by "phase" I mean the mapreduce job, which has one mapper and (optionally) one reducer. firstly you need to run the job which counts name occurences. then you need to run another job(s) to complete the task

Comment: i created 2 mappers one for each gender (just in case both gender have same name ) ,  now mapper output to reducer looks like   Mike count1 1,Gerald count1 1, Mike count1 1, Hillary count2 1, Hillary count2 1...... now is there a way to merge the original dataset for the reducer to generate final output or do we need to reduce and then focus to deriving final output?

Comment: you don't need to create 2 mappers to count males/females. you just need to do 2 emits for male and female, for example in case of `chemistry Mike Hillary` you emit `Mike_male 1` and `Hillary_female 1`, then count them up in reducer

Comment: further, for processing two input datasets (original one and counts), you may use `MultipleInputs` to set two mappers for the job (each one will process two types of input data), see this link: http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.kr/2011/09/joins-with-plain-map-reduce.html

Comment: thanks for your help. I am finding it tough to identify the appropriate key as the output should also have the "subject". Could you please give me some pointers

Comment: thanks mangusta!  was able to get to the solution :)